# How do I create a 12.04 LiveUSB for a non-PAE machine?

Tags: boot, live-usb, pae

I'm trying to create a dual-boot laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 and some flavor of Windows (TBD).  To do that, I need to do some work on partitions & install 12.04.  To do that, I need to create a bootable USB that will work with my non-PAE-capable CPU.  Someone pointed me to a mini.iso that was allegedly non-PAE-friendly, but it gave me the same error as the straightup 12.04 desktop ISO.

What version do I actually need?  (This isn't going to be a virtual machine--I don't think the laptop has the RAM to handle that happily--so enabling PAE in the virtual machineware doesn't help me.)

Comment: What cpu do you have?  Anything made in the last 10 years should support it.

Answer (score 1):

Please create your bootable USB with either the 12.04 LTS [Xubuntu Desktop](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu Desktop](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1204-now-available). Both of these still support non-PAE systems and include the non-PAE kernel.